# Digging into state in render of Reactjs app components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot reference elements of objects and arrays in a state passed to  a subcomponent.

I have not been able to clearly identify the difference between the cases when I cannot reference them in some sub components.

What is the thing I miss?

Sample props of the components is given under the components. Commented.
In that I cannot reference for example, `current.main.temp` or `current.weather[0].` it gives an `undefined` error:

```
    var Current = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var current = this.props.current;
    var dateArray = new Date(current.dt * 1000).toDateString().split(" ");
    console.log("datearray: ", dateArray[0]);
    var main = current.main;
    console.log(main);
    return (
      <div style={{float: "left", clear:"left"}}>
        <div style={{float: "left"}}>
          <div>{dateArray[0]}</div>
          <div>{dateArray[1]} {dateArray[2]}</div>
          <div>{dateArray[3]}</div>
        </div>
        <div style={{float: "left"}}>
          <div>current: {JSON.stringify(current)}</div>
        </div>
        <div style={{float: "left", clear: "right"}}>
          <div>{JSON.stringify(current.weather)}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
    // {"coord":{"lon":32.85,"lat":39.92},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":28,"pressure":1018,"humidity":34,"temp_min":28,"temp_max":28},"wind":{"speed":2.1},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1442483400,"sys":{"type":1,"id":6022,"message":0.0026,"country":"TR","sunrise":1442460682,"sunset":1442505249},"id":323786,"name":"Ankara","cod":200}
```

however, in that I can reference for example, current.main.temp or current.weather[0]:

```
var Hour = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var hour = this.props.hour; // is an object.
    return (
      <div style={{float: "left"}}>
        <div>{hour.weather[0].main}</div>
        <div>{hour.weather[0].description}</div>
        <div><img src={"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+hour.weather[0].icon+".png"} /></div>
        <div>{hour.main.temp}</div>
        <div>{hour.main.temp_min}</div>
        <div>{hour.main.temp_max}</div>
        <div>{hour.main.humidity}</div>
        <div>{new Date(hour.dt * 1000).getHours()} o,clock</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
// {"dt":1442437200,"main":{"temp":16.39,"temp_min":14.78,"temp_max":16.39,"pressure":914.76,"sea_level":1026.82,"grnd_level":914.76,"humidity":67,"temp_kf":1.62},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":1.41,"deg":308.503},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2015-09-16 21:00:00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your data structure.

You don't have any property called `data` in your weather data making `current.data.dt` and `current.data.main` be undefined.

Comment: No, I have it, just the commented sample data was wrong. I have corrected it. Also I can in my app reference those you have mentioned, `current.data.dt` and `current.data.main`.

Comment: But now I have changed it as it dores not contain a field data, and the component does not reference anything related to a data field.